# Is “An expression that has one of two values, depending on a condition.” an accurate definition of conditional expression?

Tags: python, python-3.x, conditional-statements, definition

In *Think Python, 2nd Edition*, the author defines *conditional expression* as **"An expression that has one of two values, depending on a condition."** But after I had reflected about it, I have thought that the accuracy of the definition *may* be questionable. Here's a function which is written using a conditional expression:

```
def get_sign(n):
    """Returns 1 if n is a positive number, -1 if n is a negative number,
    or 0 if n is a zero
    """
    return 1 if n > 0 else -1 if n < 0 else 0
```

Here the conditional expression is `1 if n > 0 else -1 if n < 0 else 0`. And there are two observations about that:

- the expression has one of *three* possible values, namely `1`, `-1`, or `0`.
- the value depends on two conditions, namely `n > 0`, and `n < 0`.

So, is the author's definition accurate, why and why not? Is **"An expression whose value depends on one or more conditions, and that has one of several values (at least two)."** a more accurate definition of *conditional expression*, why and why not?

Comment: For each conditional expression, there are only 2 results. It just so happens that one of the results of the first expression is another conditional expression.

Comment: An expression that evaluates one of two subexpessions, depending on a condition.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski This is a very good definition! It helps to clear the idea up. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You still have two outcomes. That one of those two outcomes is itself dependent on *another* conditional expression doesn't change this.

I've added parentheses here to illustrate my point:

```
1 if n > 0 else (-1 if n < 0 else 0)
```

So the outcome of that expression is one of these two options:

1. `1`
2. `-1 if n < 0 else 0`

That second expression is itself another conditional expression. The first value is also just an expression, which has a value once you've evaluated it; the only difference is that it produces a simple literal value. All of this makes no difference to the top-level conditional expression, it still only deals with two outcomes.

Note that only one of the expressions is actually evaluated. This matters if one of those expressions has side effects (alters state outside of the expression) or is 'expensive' in terms of memory or processing time. For example:

```
import time

def sleep10secs():
    time.sleep(10)
    return 'slow'

print('instant' if True else sleep10secs())
```

will print `instant` instantly, the `sleep10secs()` function is not called.